# Android EditTexts AutoSave

Tags: android

I have a database object which includes a lot of String fields. Right now, these string fields are managed by the user through an activity with a lot of edit texts. However, I'm having trouble saving all of the information from my EditTexts to a database. I've tried doing this when the activity calls onPause but it is not working how I would like (I'm using a ListView with the EditTexts so it's hard to say if the views will be there). I've been looking at the [text watcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) but it seems really tedious to add one for every EditText, some of which are created dynamically.

I've considered extending EditText and implementing something to use the TextWatcher but I'm again not sure about the best way to go about this.

Anybody have any suggestions on how I can accomplish this? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say you should hold a reference to each of these EditText objects in an ArrayList and then use an array list adapter to provide the data to your listview.

when any of the EditText's are changed you can call notifyDatasetChanged on the adapter.
in the onPause method you can loop thru the ArrayList and save each to your database.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think this will work but I'm going to still have to set the tag for each editText saying what field it is related to.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ideas spring to mind:

**1.**

Implement a save button at the top/bottom of the list view or in the action bar.

The save button onclicklistener would grab each text in the list view and update the relevant fields in the database.

Place the saveButton work in the UI thread so it will block until completed and the activity won't be destroyed. you could also create a progress dialog just to let users know it's being updated.

**2.**

Implement a custom adapter for your listview and in the getView() method of the adapter (you have to override this anyway)  add a text watcher dynamically... that way it's not all that arduous for you to add them individually